# How to install pygame font

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pygame

This is a beginner level question.  I am teaching myself pygame on ubuntu 
10.10.  I downloaded a couple of examples and pygame isn't working right.  I 
suspect an install problem.  But I'm not sure how to figure it out.

Is there something else I have to install to make this work?

1. My example:  http://cid-bb9549bdfdec74f4.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/PyPlotter/pyplotter.py
2. My error:

   `prompt: python pyplotter.py`

   `pyplotter.py:27: RuntimeWarning: use font: No module named font`

   `(ImportError: No module named font)`
    `font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial",12)`

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "pyplotter.py", line 27, in <module>`

`font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial",12)`

`File  "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/pygame/__init__.py",`

> line 70, in **getattr**
>     raise NotImplementedError(MissingPygameModule)`
>                    NotImplementedError: font module not available
>                    (ImportError: No module named font)

`3.`  I installed pygame with:  sudo easy_install pygame

```
This says I have the latest version of pygame.  So, Do i need to install
something different for fonts?
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of installing through easy_install, install the Ubuntu package for pygame: [python-pygame](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/python/python-pygame) (it's in universe).