# pygame on ubuntu ImportError: No module named font

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame

I'm running Python 2.7.11 on Ubuntu 14.04

I was trying to run https://github.com/asrivat1/DeepLearningVideoGames and teach my computer to play pong, but I'm stuck at a `pygame` error that I can't seem to find a solution to.

When running `deep_q_network.py` I get the following error:

```
Wrapped Game Code/pong_fun.py:31: RuntimeWarning: use font: No module named font
(ImportError: No module named font)
 font = pygame.font.SysFont("calibri",40)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "deep_q_network.py", line 7, in <module>
  import pong_fun # whichever is imported "as game" will be used
 File "Wrapped Game Code/pong_fun.py", line 31, in <module>
  font = pygame.font.SysFont("calibri",40)
 File "/home/me/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 70, in __getattr__
  raise NotImplementedError(MissingPygameModule)
NotImplementedError: font module not available
(ImportError: No module named font)
```

I installed `pygame` using `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/tlatorre pygame`.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255385/how-to-install-pygame-font

Comment: @Jérôme I did, the link in the answer gives an error

Comment: Don't mind the link. Search for pygame in your package manager (Synaptic).

Comment: All right, and then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of installing through conda install, install the Ubuntu package for pygame: python-pygame, it's in universe.

Like this

```
xyzUbuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

Comment: This worked but I had to move pygame to anaconda's site-packages.

Comment: You're usually always better off using Ubuntu repos to install via apt. This will ensure all the dependencies will be met.